# Implement global theme in React Material-UI

Tags: typescript, material-ui, react-dom

I am a little confused about React Material-UI theme.

I have tried to set it up as basic as possible and yet it seems I couldn't make it work somehow.

Below are you can find my code:

**start.tsx**

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        type: 'dark',
        primary: blue,
        secondary: lightGreen
    }
})

ReactDOM.render(
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </ThemeProvider>
    ,
    document.getElementById("root")
)

UserInterfaces.scan();
```

**app.tsx**

```
export class App extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            menu: null
        }
    }

    render() {
        if (!this.state.menu) {
            this.login();
            return <div>Loading ... </div>
        } else {
            return <div className="hx-top-frame">
                <div>
                    <MenuBar menuList={this.state.menu} />
                </div>
                <div>
                    Content here
                {/* <Content /> */}
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    }
}
```

**menubar.tsx**

```
export class MenuBar extends React.Component<IMenuProps, IMenuStates> {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { expanded: "" };
    }

    private setClose() {
        this.setState({ expanded: "" });
    }

    public render() {
        let menulist: IMenuArray[] = this.props.menuList.map<IMenuArray>(item => {
            return {
                path: item.path,
                icon: item.icon,
                link: Util.hyphenate(item.path)
            }
        })
        return <nav className="hx-menu">
            <Hidden smUp>
                <Drawer variant="temporary" anchor='left' open={this.state.expanded != ""} onClose={this.setClose.bind(this)} className="left-drawer">
                    <SubMenu menu={menulist} />
                </Drawer>
            </Hidden>
            <Hidden xsDown>
                <Drawer variant="permanent" anchor='left' open={this.state.expanded != ""} onClose={this.setClose.bind(this)} className="left-drawer">
                    <SubMenu menu={menulist}></SubMenu>
                </Drawer>
            </Hidden>
        </nav >
    }
}
```

**submenu.tsx**

```
class SubMenu extends React.Component<ISubMenuProps, IMenuStates> {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { expanded: "" };
    }

    public render() {
        let submenu: IMenuItems = {};
        let menuitems: IMenuArray[] = [];
        this.props.menu.forEach(menu => {
            let items = menu.path.split("/");
            let parent = items.length > 1;
            let name = items.shift();
            let child = items.join("/");
            if (!parent) {
                menuitems.push({ path: name, icon: menu.icon, link: menu.link });
            } else {
                if (!submenu[name]) submenu[name] = [];
                submenu[name].push({ path: child, icon: menu.icon, link: menu.link });
            }
        })

        return <List>
            {Object.keys(submenu).map(name => {
                let menu = name.split("/").shift();
                return <ListItem button className="hx-submenu" key={"m-" + name}>
                    <span className="hx-nowrap" onClick={() => { this.setState({ expanded: this.state.expanded == name ? "" : name }) }}>
                        <ListItemText primary={name} key={"t-" + name} />{this.state.expanded == name ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
                    </span>
                    <Collapse in={this.state.expanded == name} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit className="hx-submenu">
                        <SubMenu menu={submenu[name]} />
                    </Collapse>
                </ListItem>
            })}

            {menuitems.map(item => {
                return <ListItem button component={RouterLink} to={item.link} key={"i-" + item.path}>
                    <ListItemText primary={item.path} className="hx-menu" key={"l-" + item.path} />
                </ListItem>
            })}

        </List>
    }
}
```

And these below are the result.

This is when the menu is fully minimized.
[image: Result]

And this is when everything is expanded.
[image: Menu opened]

Now, my questions are:

1. Why is the right panel light grey? How to change the menu panel to blue?
2. I need the drawer to be open whenever the window has enough width. I can do the hidden part, but why does it appear on top of my content part? How to make it persistent on the left?
3. Why does the menu expand horizontally? How to make it expand vertically?
4. I don't want to make a layout for each component, and thus I don't want a stylized component. Just one global theme that I'll use throughout my project. How to do that? I've followed the documentation example, but It still went like the above examples. I don't entirely understand the document by the way, as it tends to use functions, while all my projects based on classes.

Code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/theme-test-gwutc

Thank you.

Comment: Aside from the questions regarding the global theme. I think the drawer questions must be separate ones. Not included in the same question.

Comment: @minus.273 I think, it is more in the line that the code doesn't implement it correctly? Or should I make another theme for drawer than default ones?

Comment: can you provide a codesandbox link with the code?

Comment: @Ido will try to rewrite the code. I'll post the link when done

Comment: @Ido sandbox added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll Answer 1 and 4, as for now I don't know the answers for 2,3.

1. The panel is light gray because it's the default color of Paper (Drawer uses Paper under the hood). 
   Paper is not affected by palette.primary 
   In order to change the paper background color globally, you can do this:

   ```
   const theme = createMuiTheme({
     palette: {
       type: "dark",
       primary: blue,
       secondary: lightGreen,
       background: {
         paper: "blue" // drawers (and papers) will be blue because of this line.
       }
     }
   });
   ```
2. You can very easily apply global theme to all material-ui components.
   You are already doing it by wrapping your app with ThemeProvider, all you have to do it edit your theme properly. 
   for example: if you want to override the default background color of drawers, you can also do it like that (better than option 1 above, because it is not applied for paper components):

   ```
   const theme = createMuiTheme({
     overrides: { // you declare you override default material-ui styles
      MuiDrawer: {
        paper: {
          backgroundColor: 'blue',
        }
      }
     }
   });
   ```

Comment: I meant, the *right* panel. Not the darkgray one, but the lightgray one.

Comment: Can you clarify which panel you are referring to? in your codesandbox, I can see only one panel anchored to the left. only when i hover or click it, it turns light gray

Comment: The one behind the left panel.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved them all. Number 1 and 4 as @ido has answered.

Number 2 answer, is using @ido's solution, is to put `display:flex` and set paper width to fixed number.

And this below is the answer for number 3.

**submenu.tsx**

```
.
.
<li>
    <ListItem button className="hx-submenu" key={"m-" + name}>
        <ListItemText primary={name} key={"t-" + name} onClick={() => {
            this.setState({
                expanded: this.state.expanded == name ? "" : name
            });
        }}
        />
        {this.state.expanded == name ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
    </ListItem>
    <Collapse
        in={this.state.expanded == name}
        timeout="auto"
        unmountOnExit
        className="hx-submenu"
    >
        <SubMenu menu={submenu[name]} />
    </Collapse>
</li>
.
.
```

The problem was that I put `<Collapse>` inside `<ListItem>`. Therefore, I don't see the need of `<span>`, and I removed it.

The codepen has been updated with the fixed one.